Laptop consuming about 10% battery on suspend. Is suspend failing?
When I check the sleep/suspend status (see below command and output), it appears to me that the computer enters sleep immediately but not suspend. When the computer is requested to wake it exits sleep, enters suspend, exits suspend and is back on. The computer is a bit warm during sleep/suspend and loses about 10% battery per hour. Can someone confirm what this means and what to do about this? I want to avoid having to turn off my computer every day to keep my open apps in the morning.
$ sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target


○ sleep.target - Sleep
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sleep.target; static)
 Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Sep 21 18:01:34 a70ion systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 22 08:59:57 a70ion systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Sep 22 09:22:52 a70ion systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 22 09:26:20 a70ion systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.

○ suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Sep 22 08:59:57 a70ion systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Sep 22 08:59:57 a70ion systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Sep 22 09:26:20 a70ion systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Sep 22 09:26:20 a70ion systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.

Other info: my /sys/power/mem_sleep is set to [deep].
I have a dedicated NVIDIA graphics card but this also happens if I set the power settings to use the integrated graphics only.
On my other laptop with no dedicated graphics I only lose about 1% battery per hour which is ok to me.

USB power is the one big resource hog during hibernation/suspend. Turn that off. Oh and my LG Gram I have looses a lot less (about 1% for something between 2 and 3 hours). It does have an intel XE graphs card but I doubt the graphics card drains power on hibernation.

@Rinzwind how is hibernation relevant here? Is one of the two states mentioned (sleep and suspend) actually hibernation? I never use it myself, so I really don't know. And how would one turn off USB power?

Both are "suspend" Suspend is "suspend to RAM". Hibernate is "suspend to SWAP". the 1st uses more power than the 2nd. The 2nd should be close to 0. Except for USB power if that is on the battery provides power to USB ports. I turn my notebook off myself too (7 seconds boot is quick enough for me. I do not need instant).

@Rinzwind how can I turn off the USB power? Just to mention, I don't have any USB connected while on suspend and it still drains the 10% per hour more or less.

Even worse: the system keepts the port powered in case you do insert something  ;) Check your BIOS for a setting. Where it is depends on the mobo but most are similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QJi-AMKP6w asus
